# Prevent more than 2 level menus in dashboard?

Tags: menus

In my theme I have menu for max 2 levels. Now I want prevent to create more than 2 levels menu in admin dashboard. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hey Damian, did my answer help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I investigated the codebase a bit and found a [`globalMaxDepth`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/nav-menu.js#L27) option in `wp-admin/js/nav-menu.js`.

When calling `wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth = 1` from the browser console in `/wp-admin/nav-menus.php` you are no longer able to nest more than one level per drag and drop.

To achieve your goal you can now use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to add a JS file to your backend which calls this code.

Hope this helps!